# rselenium unable to extract the required table from the given site

Tags: r, xml, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I tried running this r code but I am not getting the required table that I want.
I have taken this program from here only but still not getting the result that i should get.A little help would be highly appreciated.

```
# Start Selenium Server --------------------------------------------------------
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(magrittr)
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
#unlink(system.file("bin", package = "RSelenium"), recursive = T)
#checkForServer()
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()
# Simulate browser session and fill out form -----------------------------------

remDrv$navigate('http://agcensus.dacnet.nic.in/tehsilsummarytype.aspx')
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath","//*[@id=\"_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState\"]/option[2]")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath","//*[@id=\"_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict\"]/option[1]")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath","//*[@id=\"_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTehsil\"]/option[34]")$clickElement()
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath","//*[@id=\"_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTables\"]/option[4]")$clickElement()
# Click submit
remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath","//*[@id=\"_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit\"]")$clickElement()
# Retrieve and download results ------------------------------------------------
table <- remDrv$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  htmlParse %>% 
  readHTMLTable()%>% 
  extract2(4)


remDrv$quit()
remDrv$closeServer()

head(table)
```

instead I am getting this result

```
 V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12  V13
1                               of         1                    
2    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
>
```

Please somebody help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: the site has a bunch of links to various tables. What are you after? Getting all of them or getting a specific one?

Comment: I want to get one specific table..